# How to get the hops in a route of a connection?

Tags: c++, linux, curl, networking, routes

I'm wondering if there is a way to see the real route of a connection?

For example - if I an open connection with the server (with curl):

```
curl "http://www.google.com"
```

Is there any way to see the hopes in the route?

** traceroute is not good enough because it not necessarily go on the same route of my real request

Thanks!

Comment: If traceroute isn't sufficient, could you define your intent a little bit more to help with the best solution?

Comment: I want to now in real-time what is the route, If I run the curl command mention above, basically I open a connection with google.com and downloading the page - what was the route in this connection?

Answer (score 0):

Add the *verbose* (-v) and the *follow redirects* (-L) flags to your call:

```
curl -v -L "http://www.google.com"
```